# Parse response from FTP LIST command (syntax variations)

Tags: .net, ftp

The FTP LIST command displays a listing of all the files and directories in the current working directory. The problem is, it returns several different formats depending on the server.  Does anybody know of a .NET library that is able to parse the most popular formats?  I am OK with a "try this regex, if it fails, try the next regex" approach.

Answer (score 8):

Here's the one that I've been using for a FileZilla server:

```
^(?<dir>[\-ld])(?<permission>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})\s+(?<filecode>\d+)\s+(?<owner>\w+)\s+(?<group>\w+)\s+(?<size>\d+)\s+(?<timestamp>((?<month>\w{3})\s+(?<day>\d{2})\s+(?<hour>\d{1,2}):(?<minute>\d{2}))|((?<month>\w{3})\s+(?<day>\d{1,2})\s+(?<year>\d{4})))\s+(?<name>.+)$
```

http://chrishaas.wordpress.com/2009/06/10/regex-for-parsing-ftp-list-command/

Comment: Note that on the server I'm using, day can be 1 or 2 digits, so I had to change `(?<day>\d{2})` to `(?<day>\d{1,2})`

Comment: This seems like a great answer to me. The Op should mark this as the answer if it was what he used to overcome his issue, or provide his own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a RegEx I used on a project.  Seems to work for both Windows and Unix based FTP servers. Someone might be able to clean it up but I build it by concatenating a bunch of properties on a class.  So it's not as brutal to maintain for me.

```
^((?<DIR>([dD]{1}))|)(?<ATTRIBS>(.*))\s(?<SIZE>([0-9]{1,}))\s(?<DATE>((?<MONTHDAY>((?<MONTH>(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec))\s(?<DAY>([0-9\s]{2}))))\s(\s(?<YEAR>([0-9]{4}))|(?<TIME>([0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})))))\s(?<NAME>([A-Za-z0-9\-\._\s]{1,}))$
```

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?<dir>[\-ld])(?<permission>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})\s+(?<filecode>\d+)\s+(?<owner>\w+)\s+(?<group>\w+)\s+(?<size>\d+)\s+(?<timestamp>((?<month>\w{3})\s+(?<day>\d{1,2})\s+(?<hour>\d{1,2}):(?<minute>\d{2}))|((?<month>\w{3})\s+(?<day>\d{1,2})\s+(?<year>\d{4})))\s+(?<name>.+)$
```

Changed Chris Haas version a tiny little bit. Changed so that the day grouping can consist of a single number as well. \d{2} -> \d{1,2}

Thanks for original version.

Comment: Thanks for the update!  I updated Chris' answer to include this change.

Answer (score 0):

```
^(?<dir>[\-ld])(?<permission>([\-r][\-w][\-xs]){3})\s+(?<filecode>\d+)\s+(?<owner>\S+)\s+(?<group>\S+)\s+(?<size>\d+)\s+(?<timestamp>((?<month>\w{3})\s+(?<day>\d{1,2})\s+(?<hour>\d{1,2}):(?<minute>\d{2}))|((?<month>\w{3})\s+(?<day>\d{1,2})\s+(?<year>\d{4})))\s+(?<name>.+)$
```

On the site I'm on, the owner is displayed in Email address format.  I changed owner and group to be non-space characters instead of word characters.

This is expanding on Yodiz' version of Chris Haas' version. Thanks so much!