# List only files and Last Modify Date of a FTP server with C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp

I'm trying to parse the result of the Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails command, I want just the FileName and the last modification date Not Directories.

The command returns this:

"01-21-09  06:16PM                 rattandom"
"01-21-09  08:01PM               9900   myfile.txt"

Does somebody know the way to parse it? I was reading and if the server is Windows or Unix it will return something different. The result that I paste is for an FTP in a Windows 2003 Server

Answer (score 4):

FTP list results are non-standard so every FTP server could potentially return something different.

Comment: You will have different parsing for every possible FTP server you might see.  There is no consistent format to get the information you want.

Comment: +1 I didn't know that, but if that's true, it really sucks to implement an ftp client.

Comment: This is why some FTP clients won't work with certain servers yet other clients have no issue.

Answer (score 1):

There is a suggested regular exception that works on both Windows and Unix based FTP servers. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/966578/parse-response-from-ftp-list-command-syntax-variations/966884#966884).

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [Ftp.dll FTP component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/ftp/) it pareses most UNIX and Windows LIST command responses:

```
using (Ftp client = new Ftp())
{
    client.Connect("ftp.example.org");
    client.Login("user", "password");

    List<FtpItem> items = client.GetList();

    foreach (FtpItem item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Name:        {0}", item.Name);
        Console.WriteLine("Size:        {0}", item.Size);
        Console.WriteLine("Modify date: {0}", item.ModifyDate);

        Console.WriteLine("Is folder:   {0}", item.IsFolder);
        Console.WriteLine("Is file:     {0}", item.IsFile);
        Console.WriteLine("Is symlink:  {0}", item.IsSymlink);

        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    client.Close();
}
```

Please note that this is a commercial product I created.